# Find the min value of $x+1/x$ on $(0, \infty)$ without using calculus.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Using calculus, it is pretty obvious. I was trying to see if it can be done without calculus. May be some sort of inequalities.

Comment: $f(x)=x+1/x\implies f(x)=f(1/x)\implies f(1)=2$ is a relative maxima or minima of $f(x)$, since $f(x)=f(1/x)$, so no other points can be relative maxima or minima since every other point is equal to another, then it is nearly needed to graph to see whether it is a maxima or minima.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With AM-GM we get $$x+\frac { 1 }{ x } \ge 2\sqrt { x\frac { 1 }{ x }  } =2$$

Comment: (which is obviously attained by a specific value of $x$)

Comment: "with equality if and only if $x = \frac{1}{x}$''.

Answer (score 10):

**Hint**. One may observe that,
$$
\left(x+\frac1x \right)^2-4=\left(x-\frac1x \right)^2\ge0, \qquad x>0.
$$

Comment: This turns out to be exactly the same as the other answer, since this consideration is one way of proving the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: @MorganRogers Actually, this answer uses considerably weaker assumptions than AM-GM.  The AM-GM can be proved from the principle that no (real) square is negative, but it is a stronger result, consequently stronger than is needed to prove the original statement.

Comment: @heropup For AM-GM the only assumption is that the terms are real and non-negative, so I'm pretty sure it's the same..?

Comment: @MorganRogers $$(x_1 - x_2)^2 \ge 0$$ is definitely a weaker claim than $$(x_1 + \cdots + x_n)/n \ge (x_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot x_n)^{1/n}.$$  To prove the latter from the former, one would probably apply some induction argument.

Comment: @heropup You can indeed prove the latter from the former by induction, with no further assumptions. Then given the latter at $n=2$,
$$(x_1+x_2)/2 \geq (x_1 x_2)^{1/2} \implies (x_1 - x_2)^2 \geq 0.$$
So the two are equivalent.

Comment: @MorganRogers If one needs to prove the latter from the former by employing induction, that is a lot more mathematics that one would be using; consequently why I said at the very beginning "the former is **weaker** than the latter."  That is not the same as saying they are "not equivalent."  If one can prove a statement using more elementary machinery, that is **precisely** what is meant by using "weaker assumptions."

Comment: @MorganRogers To illustrate:  One can use Fermat's Last Theorem to prove that $x^4 + y^4 = z^4$ has no nontrivial integer solutions, but that is a **lot** stronger machinery (involving proving the modularity theorem) than simply using Fermat's original argument of proof by contradiction via infinite descent.  Does that mean one cannot prove FLT first, that it does not follow from more elementary principles?  No.  But it is considerably more mathematics than needed.

Comment: @heropup That comparison is a little strong. To prove AM-GM for two variables you can use the exact manipulation you have exhibited in your answer, and for the problem at hand a simple substitution suffices from there.  The assumptions on the variables are the same. I agree that the broader statement of AM-GM is stronger than was needed here, but given several problems of this kind it would be inefficient *not* to prove AM-GM from first principles (at least for two variables) and to apply that directly.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$. Clearly $f(x)=f(1/x)$, so we minimize in $[1,\infty)$

Notice $x+\frac{1}{x}>1+1\iff x-1>1-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{x-1}{x}$, which is clear since $x\geq 1$

Answer (score 2):

$x+1/x\ge m$ for all positive $x$ iff the same $x$ satisfy $x^2-mx+1\ge0$. Clearly $m\le2$. But if $m<2$ then $x^2-mx+1>(x-1)^2\ge0$, so $m=2$.

Answer (score -1):

$(x-1)^2 \geq 0$ for $x>0$. This, in turn, implies that $x+1/x\geq 2$ for all $x>0$. I have left the details. So, the min value of $x+1/x$ is 2 on $x>0$.